# How to create point cloud data using webcam

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am using ros indigo. Is it possible to create point cloud data using webcam in ros?  Is there any packages available for the conversion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271381/how-to-create-point-cloud-data-using-webcam/) by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2017-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes , you can use monocular dense slam such as : [Dso](https://github.com/JakobEngel/dso) , [LSD_SLAM](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam) ...

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2017-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1